# Add photo Bucket to my phpfox site

Tags: php, javascript, html, photobucket, phpfox

I need to add photo bucket in to my site. i already added flicker photo import module in my site. But need to add photo bucket as well.
How can i do this?
need some help.
Thanks
Akila

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you mean a photobucket slideshow.  You can create your slideshow here:
http://photobucket.com/slideshows

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for slider on HTML pages.

Have a look at the following tutorials to apply photo slider on your images.

http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/

http://www.dreamcss.com/2009/04/create-beautiful-jquery-sliders.html

Hope this will Help..

Thanks!

Hussain

Comment: Hi Hussain
Actually what i need is when i click the button it will display the search box with button and 
when insert the key value (ex:- flower) it will display all the flower images from photo bucket.
Then we can select and add to our site.

Thanx Alika

Comment: Hi Akila, I don't think so you will find any ready made plugin for it. Your bucket needs some javascript programming to get it done. You can try to customize following sliders http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-image-galleries/. Also http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/#1 seems to be easy for customization.. Thanks